# Can a phrase including past participle be put right behind the preposition 'of'?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-usage, is-it-a-rule, descriptive-grammar

For all the English grammar my teacher taught me, the element put right behind the preposition 'of' can be:
 1. a noun. The *leg of the desk*
 2. gerund leading phrase which acts as a noun: The result *of giving* your children anything they want.
 3. gerund leading phrase which starts with possessive pronoun: The good effect *of my giving* you aid in time.

However, recently I read such sentence structure behind the preposition 'of', for instance,

> - The spectacle *of gunners using* science of shatter men's body
> - The result *of accumulated knowledge* applied to practical life

The two examples above are not in the three conditions I know about the usage of preposition 'of'.

Can anybody analyze the grammar for me?? I make the following sentences when I try to imitate the example, and please see if they are right or not.

> - The consequence of the troops occupying the abandoned factory
> - The finding of Gus abducted and sent to an unknown place 10 years ago

Comment: You need to modify your title to *Can a phrase which includes a past participle be put right behind the preposition 'of'?*, either this way or another.

Answer (score -1):

You were lied to.

All prepositional phrases start with a preposition and are followed to their right by an arbitrary **noun phrase**, not merely by a noun. There are many ways of constructing noun phrases.

This an example of why you shouldn’t believe what you were mistaught. You may use it if you want: it’s one of mine.